# in minds or in mind

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say "What do you (more than 1 person) have in **minds**?" or we should say "What do you have in mind?". If both of the sentences are correct, which one is more idiomatic?

Comment: You say, to a group "What do you [guys, fellas, all, people,...] *have **in** mind*?" (singular). You could also say "*What's **on** your minds*?" (plural). The distinction is the former speaks of *containment*, and the latter of *placement*. But be warned: the two idioms have very different connotations (the second means, essentially, "*What's bothering you [guys]*?"). Anyway, that's why you cannot say "*What do you have **in minds***?" (*in* + plural); it breaks the metaphor of containment.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, especially because you mentioned something new to me, I mean "containment" and "placement, which I can read about more.

Comment: Mok: no problem! But note that the word "on" is about *placement*, not *replacement* (no *re*-); the soup is *in* the bowl, but the bowl is *on* the table. The bowl is placed on the table (*placement*).

Comment: Though I appreciate mplungjan's answer, Dan Bron's answer sounds great to me, and I think it would help more people if you could post it as an answer.

Comment: Alright, let me format it a bit then.

Comment: Suggest migration to [ELL.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say, to a group

> What do you [*guys*, *fellas*, *all*, *people*,...] **have in mind**? (singular)

It is possible to use use the plural; for example, you could also say

> ***What's on your minds***?" (plural)

The distinction is the former, using *in*, speaks of containment, and the latter, using *on*, of placement.

**But be warned**: the two idioms have very different connotations. The second means, essentially, "*What's bothering you* [*guys*]?".

Anyway, that's why you **cannot** say "*What do you have in minds*?" (*in* + plural); it breaks the metaphor of containment.

Answer (score 0):

> What do you have in mind

is the idiomatic version of what would you (one person or multiple) like to do

You might ask one person

> What is on your mind

or more than one

> What is on your minds

which is mostly used to inquire if there is a problem

Comment: Please add a note about the different  connotations of these two constructions (otherwise, we're just setting up a trap for OP).